# Excel how to show most repeated name from a range?

Tags: excel, vba

My `Column A` has

```
Apple
Orange
Apple
Aple
Mango

Column B

Apple
Mango
Apple
Mango
Mango

Column C

Apple
Apple
Apple
Apple
Apple
```

to show most repeated names on a single column (Like Column A) i use this code-

```
=INDEX(A1:A5,MODE(IF(A1:A5<>0,MATCH(A1:A5,A1:A5,0))))
```

Code returns most repeated name of col.A: `Apple`

But that code works fine for single column only. While working with three column its not working. What should I do? I've tried to change `A1: C5` but its not working.

Comment: Do you want to know the most repeated value for each column or do you want the most repeated value in the range?

Comment: @AxGryndr: Range. most repeated value in the range. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This "array formula" will get the most repeated text

`=INDIRECT("R"&TEXT(MIN(IF(COUNTIF(A1:C5,A1:C5)=MAX(COUNTIF(A1:C5,A1:C5)),ROW(A1:C5)*1000+COLUMN(A1:C5))),"0\C000"),0)`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

That will work for ranges up to 999 columns - if there are ties it will only give the first one, working across each row first

Answer (score 0):

Here's and idea.

You find the most repeated word of each column and put the result into a results column. So the most repeated word result of `column A` would be in `column D row 1`, the most repeated word result of `column B` would be in `column D row 2`, and the most repeated word result of `column C` would be in `column D row 3`. Then you find the most repeated word in `column D`, hence giving you the most repeated word from all the columns.

Or you could use [a PowerShell script](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/04/03/excel-spreadsheets.aspx).

Comment: That actually doesn't work because the most values in a range isn't always the most value in a column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub MostDupesInRange()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim dupes As Long
    Dim maxDupes As Long
    Dim dupeWord As String
    Dim dupeTie As Boolean

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1:D8")

    For Each cell In rng
        dupes = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, cell)
        If dupes > maxDupes Then
            maxDupes = dupes
            dupeWord = cell.Value
            dupeTie = False
        End If
        If dupes = maxDupes And InStr(1, dupeWord, cell.Value) = False Then
            dupeWord = dupeWord & ", " & cell.Value
            dupeTie = True
        End If
    Next cell
    If dupeTie = False Then MsgBox dupeWord & "" _
        & "appears in the range " & maxDupes & " times."
    If dupeTie = True Then MsgBox "The values (" & _
        dupeWord & ") appear in the range " & maxDupes & " times."
End Sub
```

**NOTE:** This will also detect if there is a tie for values with the most duplicates. My initial answer didn't include this, but it irritated me to leave it incomplete.